# How to merge or handle duplicate column in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a df that looks like this:

```
column1 columnId   column1
aaa        1        
bbb        2       bbb
ccc        3
```

Is there anyway I can take all my duplicate columns and merge them with existing data?

New df would look like this:

```
column1 columnId  
aaa        1        
bbb        2       
ccc        3
```

note, this is an example I have 18 duplicate columns but deduplicated I have 9.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have to merge. Just drop the duplicate column.

Comment: the issue is that I dont know what data to drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `first`

```
df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
Out[915]: 
  column1  columnId
0     aaa         1
1     bbb         2
2     ccc         3
```